# How to make a class with 'dynamic' data types?

Tags: c++, vector, types

In the C++ standard library, there is `std::vector`, and you can specify the type you want to put into a vector while declaring it.

I want to create a class which would contain a vector of either strings, or ints, or whatever I would ever need. Is it possible to do this in an easy way, or would I have to write thousands of lines in C and assembly?

Comment: You can have a vector of [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any).

Comment: Or a vector of [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant), if the number of possible types is limited, and known at compile-time. Note that both `std::variant` and `std::any` require C++17 or higher.

Comment: You can create a template class. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_templates.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the data type in the declaration, you can instantiate different kinds of vectors: `vector<int> myint_v; vector<string> mystring_v;` etc.... but I think your asking about how to make a *Generic* class and [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generics-in-c/) has a really good article on this.

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

template <typename T> 
class Array { 
private: 
    T* ptr; 
    int size; 

public: 
    Array(T arr[], int s); 
    void print(); 
}; 

template <typename T> 
Array<T>::Array(T arr[], int s) 
{ 
    ptr = new T[s]; 
    size = s; 
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
        ptr[i] = arr[i]; 
} 

template <typename T> 
void Array<T>::print() 
{ 
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
        cout << " " << *(ptr + i); 
    cout << endl; 
} 

int main() 
{ 
    int arr[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; 
    Array<int> a(arr, 5); 
    a.print(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

That's just an example of using a template to declare a methods in a class. Hopefully that helps. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

C++ has variant and any.  Variant supports a fixed list of alternative types; any supports any type of object that can be copied.

Now, any is really tricky to use right; in order to get back your data, you have to know what type of data (exactly) is in the any.  And often variant is all you need.

If your goal is something akin to a json structure, well there are plenty of implementations of that.

Answer (score -1):

I want to add a major difference. `std::variant` is a compile time feature where `std::any` is runtime.

Generally, what you want is `std::any`. Variant is a type safe union which somehow breaks what the original union was designed for (to overlook types at runtime as well).

The benefit of std::any is that your don't have to change often a type which can contain a std::any instead of constantly changing the data (and, for example, to recompile the entire precompilation headers). The drawback is that you have to ensure that it contains the type you want, or you get an exception when using std::any_cast. There is added overhead as well.

The final advice is to avoid using any of the two, unless there is a good reason. There are safer ways to use multiple types (polymorphism). As said, your can also put your data inside an object like json or XML.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can do via some sort of manipulation. Easiest method so far i have would be using std::pair<type1,type2> method. I will initiliaze with string and double which would be able to hold most of the things you need. String can hold single character to whole text and double pretty much same thing for the number.

Easiest way is,

```
vector<pair<type1,type2>> vector_name;
```

Then push each value via make_pair method

```
vector_name.push_back(make_pair(type1 Value, type2 Value));
```

When accessing it .first is for type1 and .second would be for type2. You can see more in the code below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
     vector<pair<string, double>> mypair;
     mypair.push_back(make_pair("HelloWorld!", 8.2021));
     mypair.push_back(make_pair("!", 8));
     for(auto &&i:mypair){
         cout << i.first << " " << i.second << "\n";
     }
     return 0;
 }
```